# Unable to plot regression line correctly with scatter plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm following a course on EdX on Programming with Python in Data Science. When using a given function to plot the results of my linear regression model, the graph seems very off with all the scatter points clustered at the bottom and the regression line way up top.

I'm not sure if it is the defined function `drawLine` to be incorrect or sth else is wrong with my modeling process.

here is the defined function

```
def drawLine(model, X_test, y_test, title, R2):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.scatter(X_test, y_test, c='g', marker='o')
    ax.plot(X_test, model.predict(X_test), color='orange', linewidth=1, alpha=0.7)

    title += " R2: " + str(R2)
    ax.set_title(title)
    print(title)
    print("Intercept(s): ", model.intercept_)

    plt.show()
```

here is the code I wrote

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot') # Look Pretty

# Reading in data
X = pd.read_csv('Datasets/College.csv', index_col=0)

# Wrangling data
X.Private = X.Private.map({'Yes':1, 'No':0})

# Splitting data
roomBoard = X[['Room.Board']]
accStudent = X[['Accept']]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(roomBoard, accStudent, test_size=0.3, random_state=7)

# Training model
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
score = model.score(X_test, y_test)

# Visualise results
drawLine(model, X_test, y_test, "Accept(Room&Board)", score)
```

the data I used can be found [here](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/College.csv)

Thank you for your time.
Any help or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you drawLine function I changed `ax.scatter` to `plt.scatter`. I also changed `roomBoard` and `accStudent` to numpy arrays instead of pandas.Series. Finally I changed how you were updating the "private" column to

```
X.loc[:, "Private"] = X.Private.map({'Yes':1, 'No':0})
```

The [Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics) explain why I made this change. Other small changes are cosmetic.

I got the following to work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot') # Look Pretty

# Reading in data
X = pd.read_csv('College.csv', index_col=0)

# Wrangling data
X.loc[:, "Private"] = X.Private.map({'Yes':1, 'No':0})

# Splitting data
roomBoard = X.loc[:, 'Room.Board'].values.reshape((len(X),1))
accStudent = X.loc[:, 'Accept'].values.reshape((len(X),1))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(roomBoard, accStudent, test_size=0.3, random_state=7)

# Training model
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
score = model.score(X_test, y_test)

# Visualise results
def drawLine(model, X_test, y_test, title, R2):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.scatter(X_test, y_test, c='g', marker='o')
    y_pred =  model.predict(X_test)
    plt.plot(X_test, y_pred, color='orange', linewidth=1, alpha=0.7)

    title += " R2: " + str(R2)
    ax.set_title(title)
    print(title)
    print("Intercept(s): ", model.intercept_)

    plt.xticks(())
    plt.yticks(())

    plt.show()

drawLine(model, X_test, y_test, "Accept(Room&Board)", score)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it worked! I tried to make one change at a time and realised the types of `roomBoard` and `accStudent` seemed to be the most important to create a correct graph. However, I'm pretty sure in my original code `roomBoard = X[['Room.Board']]` returns a pandas.DataFrame. Could you enlighten me on why a numpy 2DArray works while a DataFrame doesn't?

Comment: [Scikit-Learn Docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) say the input must be a numpy array